# Using a tkinter Canvas to display an image then drawing on the image using cv2.circle/cv2.line

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, opencv, python-3.8

I am relatively new to Python and I am trying to build a GUI using `tkinter`, utilising the features of `cv2`.

I wish to bring in an image (`tk.Canvas` currently used to display), use an `tk.Entry` box to create a list of components from the user, create radio buttons from the users inputs and then draw circles on the image using mouse clicks, each component in a different colour.

So far I have successfully created the `tkinter` window that does all of the above apart from draw on the image. I have a separate code that I initially created to draw the `cv2.circles` onto a JPEG that works fine, I just do not know how to link the tkinter GUI to the `cv2` library.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I cannot find anything asking the same question. I have attached part of the code below...

Best,
George

**The function for selecting the file path, importing the image, and displaying it on a canvas:**

```
    def selecting_file(self):
    self.file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

    self.cv_img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(self.file_path), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    self.height, self.width, self.no_channels = self.cv_img.shape


    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.window, width=self.width, height=self.height)
    self.canvas.pack()

    self.photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=PIL.Image.fromarray(self.cv_img))

    self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.photo, anchor=tk.NW)
    self.label = tk.Label(image=self.photo)
    self.label.image = self.photo
```

**The functions for creating the radio buttons and then obtaining the values from them:**

```
    def compile_radio(self):
    self.v = tk.StringVar()
    for i in App.part_list:
        self.radio = tk.Radiobutton(self.window, text=i, variable=self.v, value=App.part_list.index(i)+1, command=self.radio_select)
        self.radio.pack()

val = 0
def radio_select(self):
    self.radio_value = self.v.get()
    self.radio_value = App.val
```

**The function and code that is not within this script that allows to draw the circles onto a cv2.imshow:**

```
def draw_circle1(event, x, y, flags, param):
if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
    cv2.circle(img, center = (x, y), radius = 5, color = (0,0,255), thickness = 2)
    global red_count
    red_count += 1

img = cv2.imread('IMAGE.jpg')
cv2.namedWindow(winname = 'Drawing')
cv2.setMouseCallback('Drawing', draw_circle1)

while True:
    cv2.imshow('Drawing',img)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: maybe better use `tkinter` events to get position - `canvas.bind("<Button-1>", function)`. and `PIL`  or `canvas` to draw circle/line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use `cv2` to draw it. You can use `tkinter` and `PIL` for this.

First you have to load image as normal PIL `image`

```
self.image = Image.open(self.file_path)

self.width, self.height = self.image.size
```

and next you have to create `photo` for displaying on canvas and `draw` for drawing and save it.

```
self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.image)

self.draw  = ImageDraw.Draw(self.image)
```

You can use `tkinter` to select place on displayed image

```
self.canvas.bind('<Button-1>', self.draw_circle)
```

and run function which will draw circle on canvas and on `draw` which can be save.

```
# display on canvas
self.canvas.create_oval((event.x-5, event.y-5, event.x+5, event.y+5), width=2, outline='#FF0000')

# draw on self.image
self.draw.ellipse((event.x-5, event.y-5, event.x+5, event.y+5), width=2, outline=(255,0,0))
```

And later you can save it

```
self.image.save('output.jpg')
```

---

BTW: if you use `Canvas` to display image then you don't need to use `Label`.

---

Minimal working code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image, ImageDraw
        
class App():

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.after(100, self.selecting_file)
        self.window.mainloop()

    def selecting_file(self):
        self.file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        #self.file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='images/', initialfile='example.jpg')

        self.image = Image.open(self.file_path)
        self.width, self.height = self.image.size

        self.draw  = ImageDraw.Draw(self.image)
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.image)
        
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.window, width=self.width, height=self.height)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.canvas.bind('<Button-1>', self.draw_circle)

        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.photo, anchor=tk.NW)

        self.save_button = tk.Button(self.window, text='Save', command=self.save)
        self.save_button.pack()

    def draw_circle(self, event):
        # display on canvas
        self.canvas.create_oval((event.x-5, event.y-5, event.x+5, event.y+5), width=2, outline='#FF0000')
        # draw on self.image
        self.draw.ellipse((event.x-5, event.y-5, event.x+5, event.y+5), width=2, outline=(255,0,0))

    def save(self):
        self.image.save('output.jpg')

# --- main ---

App()
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

Version with buttons to change color, figure and radius.

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, colorchooser
from PIL import ImageTk, Image, ImageDraw


class App():

    def __init__(self):
        self.color = '#FF0000'
        self.figure = 'circle'
        self.figure = 'rectangle'
        self.size = 5
        
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.after(100, self.selecting_file)
        self.window.mainloop()

    def selecting_file(self):
        self.file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        #self.file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='images/', initialfile='example.jpg')
            
        self.image = Image.open(self.file_path)
        self.width, self.height = self.image.size

        self.draw  = ImageDraw.Draw(self.image)
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.image)

        self.frame_tools = tk.Frame(self.window)
        self.frame_tools.pack()
        
        self.rectangle_button = tk.Button(self.frame_tools, text='Rectangle', command=lambda:self.change_figure('rectangle'))
        self.rectangle_button.pack(side='left')
        self.circle_button = tk.Button(self.frame_tools, text='Circle', command=lambda:self.change_figure('circle'))
        self.circle_button.pack(side='left')
        self.size_entry = tk.Entry(self.frame_tools)
        self.size_entry.bind('<Return>', self.change_size)
        self.size_entry.pack(side='left')
        
        self.color_button = tk.Button(self.frame_tools, text='Color: #FF0000', command=self.change_color)
        self.color_button.pack(side='left')
        
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.window, width=self.width, height=self.height)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.bind('<Button-1>', self.on_click)

        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.photo, anchor=tk.NW)

        self.save_button = tk.Button(self.window, text='Save', command=self.save)
        self.save_button.pack()

    def on_click(self, event):
        if self.figure == 'circle':
            self.draw_circle(event)
        elif self.figure == 'rectangle':
            self.draw_rectangle(event)
            
    def draw_circle(self, event):
        x1 = event.x - self.size
        y1 = event.y - self.size
        x2 = event.x + self.size
        y2 = event.y + self.size
        # display on canvas
        self.canvas.create_oval((x1, y1, x2, y2), width=2, outline=self.color)
        # draw on self.image
        self.draw.ellipse((x1, y1, x2, y2), width=2, outline=self.color)

    def draw_rectangle(self, event):
        x1 = event.x - self.size
        y1 = event.y - self.size
        x2 = event.x + self.size
        y2 = event.y + self.size
        # display on canvas
        self.canvas.create_rectangle((x1, y1, x2, y2), width=2, outline=self.color)
        # draw on self.image
        self.draw.rectangle((x1, y1, x2, y2), width=2, outline=self.color)

    def save(self):
        self.image.save('output.jpg')

    def change_color(self):
        rgb, color_string = colorchooser.askcolor(initialcolor=self.color)
        #print(rgb, color_string)
        if color_string:
            self.color = color_string
            self.color_button['text'] = 'Color: ' + color_string

    def change_figure(self, figure):
        self.figure = figure

    def change_size(self, event=None):
        try:
            self.size = int(self.size_entry.get())
        except Exceptions as ex:
            print(ex)
# --- main ---

App()
```